45 days to mars would the reduction ratio hold throughout the solar system?
I've heard some proposals that say they could make it to mars in as little as 45 days when the current average time to mars is 200 days. Is it likely this reduction ratio would remain the same throughout the solar system? Assuming the figures being decided by the reduction factor which is slightly more than quartering is the time for direct trajectories for any planets that have had direct trajectories taken to them before.

Which proposals are you referring to?

Interesting idea but it would help to provide some more context. Do you have an idea of the scale of mission / how far in the future considered by the proposals you mention.

It will not remain the same. Reasons:

Planetary orbits are not on a flat plane as depicted in many movies or shows. If you have ever played Kerbal Space Program with Realism Overhaul and Real Solar System, you will know that there are different inclinations as well as orbit shapes. For example: Mars has a near perfect circular orbit but a planet like Pluto has an elliptical orbit with its periapsis actually below the orbit of Neptune.
Acceleration. Spacecraft can only accelerate and slow down at a certain rate. The reason why you can shrink it down to 45 days is because the spacecraft’s engines have the capability to accelerate it to that speed, then slow it down, within 45 days. For a mission to Saturn for example (I also got the times from a kerbal space program realism overhaul, real solar system video link here: 

 ) Pioneer space probe took 6 and a half years to reach Saturn whereas a far future mission could take just 355 days to get to Saturn it is however, not the same reduction ratio.


With that far future mission do you have a time to Jupiter? The reduction ratio was actually more one year instead of six and a half and for context what time to mars do those times to Jupiter and Saturn correspond to?

there are times where referring to Kerbal Space Program is fine, but as the basis of a whole answer it's insufficient

However without the reference do you have any estimates for me?

@ErinAnne I think it’s acceptable in this case. It’s not the basis for the first point, it’s just a reference (knowing those eccentricities/inclinations doesn’t at all require KSP), and there’s another completely-non-KSP point made.

I wouldn't call Mars' orbit "near perfect circular" With an orbital eccentricity of 0.0934, it's more elliptical than any other planet except Mercury, with an aphelion more than 20% further from the Sun than its perihelion. Using the circular assumption when plotting courses will result in missing the planet by millions of kilometers.
